# DialogFlow Conv shows user status as Guest

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am experiencing issues with DialogFlow 'Conv' command showing the user as a guest instead of a verified user.

Has anyone else experienced any similar issues, the status shows Guest even when using the simulator.

I have followed Google's guidance, as per the link below, to no avail:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/save-data#determining_and_handling_user_verification_status

Comment: In your web activity settings, have you also checked the include chrome history checkbox?

Comment: Hi, yes that's been checked